# How can I find/highlight recurring values in multiple columns on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I need to find/highlight duplicate values which occur in each of the 8 columns within my worksheet [(found here)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rf-J59Bm7FvgEIDLrPnaUqolsrmqcK0BcPTknAxZb44/edit?usp=sharing). The columns are from D0 to D8 and have varrying rows in them. I have tried solutions provided [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4056-excel-find-common-values-in-3-columns.html). The solutions I used are;

> (1)
>   =LOOKUP("zzz",CHOOSE({1,2},"",INDEX(A$2:A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(E$1:E1,A$2:A$10)+IF(IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,A$2:A$10)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$9,A$2:A$10)>0,1,0)=2,0,1),0))))

and

> (2)
>   =INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$10)+IF(IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8, $A$2:$A$10)>0, 1,
>   0)+IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$9, $A$2:$A$10)>0, 1, 0)=2, 0, 1), 0))

I substituted the values as per my own worksheet but each time I just got "0" as an answer even though that is not possible. Just by looking at the first 2 rows one can easily tell that there are values which occured in all 8 columns.

I am a beginner in Excel and currently using Microsoft Excel 2016 for Mac (Ver 16.16.14).

Comment: I have amended my solution and I think I have found the problem from the sample answer. Let me know if my solution is not working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

Found an error within the nested **IF** functions from the second formula you provided.

In the formula you tried to do `IF(IF(A)+IF(B)=2,0,1)` but the correct way should be `IF((IF(A)+IF(B))=2,0,1)` in my opinion.

Based on the sample worksheet you provided, enter the following formula in Cell `J2`:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$861,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(J$1:J1,A$2:A$861)+IF((IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$243,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$162,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(D$2:D$132,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(E$2:E$118,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(F$2:F$112,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(G$2:G$94,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(H$2:H$81,A$2:A$861)>0,1,0))=7,0,1),0))
```

Please note it is an **array formula** so you need to do the following after entered the above formula:

> **Select the range**, press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and then press <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>RETURN</kbd>
>
> In case the above does not work for you:
>
> Select the range, press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and then press <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>RETURN</kbd>

Please read this if you are still unclear: [How to Use Array Formula in Excel Mac](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-use-array-formula-in-excel-mac/e178f9a2-bb3e-4a06-8c2b-e9ff96ffca10) (Who'd knew using array formula in Excel for Mac is such a pain...)

Drag the formula down until the list is returning `#N/A` error which means you have found all common values.

Suppose you have **named** this list of common values as **List**, my experience in Excel 2016 for Windows is that you go back to your source table, highlight the whole table, go to **Conditional Formatting** under `Home Tab`, go to `New Rule...`, go to the last option, and enter the following formula as the formatting rule:

```
=MATCH(A2,List,0)>0
```

[image: Example]

> Given that **Power Query** is not supported in `Excel 2011 and Excel 2016 for Mac`, please disregard the following approach using **Power Query**. FYI power query approach is way faster than the above array formula approach in this case...

Judging from your post and the example you provided, I think you want to find common values that have presented in **all** 8 Columns, which means you will ignore values that appeared in 7, 6, 5 or lesser columns.

Given that you are dealing with a large data set (`860 x 8`), I suggest to use **Power Query** to tackle the problem. Power Query is a built-in function in Excel 2010 Professional Plus and all later versions of Excel.

Steps are:

1. Use **From Table** function under `Data` tab to load your data to the Power Query Editor;
2. Highlight all columns, then use **Unpivot Columns** function under `Transform` tab to transform the table into a 2-Column table;
3. Use **Group By** function under `Transform` tab group `Value` column by counting distinct rows as set out below;

[image: Group By]

4. Right click the **filer** box on the right of the column header to filer the list by `8` which will return values that appeared in all 8 columns;
5. **Close & Load** the column (which is actually a one-column table) to a new worksheet (by default).

[image: Common Values]

Here are the power query **M codes** behind the scene for reference only. All steps are using built-in functions of the editor which is quite straight forward.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"d0", Int64.Type}, {"d1", Int64.Type}, {"d2", Int64.Type}, {"d3", Int64.Type}, {"d4", Int64.Type}, {"d5", Int64.Type}, {"d6", Int64.Type}, {"d7", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(Table.Distinct(_)), type number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([Count] = 8)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Count"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: So I have started off with the error in the nested IF statement and after applying your updated formula I am getting an errror, "circular dependecy detected"

Comment: So pasted the formula in K1 and then used control+shift+ enter (mac) and got only 1 value in K1. I am pretty positive that there are other common values as well.

Comment: Ok dragged the first value cell down and got 29 common value till i start seeing #NA :) got my answer! Now to try to find out how to get values which occur 7 times in any of those 8 columns :)

Comment: @shahz you need to start from the second row so if you paste the formula in K1 it will have circular reference error.

Comment: I have accepted your answer :) I also changed the =7 to =6 but it is still giving me values which occurred in all 8 columns.

Comment: @shahz I just tested and in order to find the value that occurred 7 times in any of the 8 columns, you may need to use 8 helper columns, the formula in each column is `COUNTIFS(ColumnB:H, A2)`, `COUNTIFS(ColumnA, B2, columnC:H, B2)`, `COUNTIFS(columnA:B, C2, columnD:H)`.... until `COUNTIFS(columnA:G, H2)`. Drag these formulas down to Row 861. Then any value that returns `6`count will be the value you are looking for. You may want to give it a go and let me know how you go. Actually this method can also tell you which values appeared 8 times as they should return `7` count in other columns.

Comment: so what  I have been doing is using the same formula for 8 to 2 days but only changed the position as per where the formula was being entered and for 8 days i kept it >7 and then for each day i just kept on decreasing the number i.e. for 6 days i kept >5. It gave me the IDs I wanted :) I also used another method to double check if I was getting the right answers and I was :) Thank you once again for your help!